# Selenium: CheckBox not interactable (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to run this line of code
`chrome.find_element_by_css_selector("#order_terms_and_conditions").click()`

the link i'm running this on is:
https://www.off---white.com/en/GB/checkout (to get here you'll have to add an item to your cart).

When I run that command though, it says that the Element is not interactable. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Which element is that you're trying to interact with? Could you provide some images to have a better understanding of you issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the element is considered invisible when interacting with selenium by clicking it.

The following will work:

```
check_conditions = chrome.find_element_by_css_selector("#order_terms_and_conditions")

chrome.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", check_conditions)
```

Let me know if that help.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!